# How deploy Web application in Azure VM using Visual studio online

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I am very new to the visual studio online. It part of POC. I was try to deploy the web application in the Azure. I could successfully deploy the web application in the azure website. Later I have created and Azure Virtual Machine (VM) and try to deploy the application to VM. But I could not. I have read through some of the blogs but not able to figure out how deploy to the VM using Visual Studio Online. I was able to publish the application to the Azure VM using Visual Studio 2015. But failed to deploy via Visual Studio Online.

I am using Build definitions . Please help me to configure the deployment in Azure VM using VSO.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if using DevOps Projects in Azure helps you with your requirement:

Deploy your ASP.NET app to Azure virtual machines by using Azure DevOps Projects: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops-project/azure-devops-project-vms

Depending on the type of application you're building, you may choose one of the [Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/?view=azure-devops#build) Tasks mentioned in the catalog. And then, proceed with the deployment using a suitable [Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/?view=azure-devops#deploy) task. The above tutorial uses the [Azure Resource Group Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops) task.

Hope this helps!